# Talend ESB: How to Consume messages from Queue Only When Database end point is running?

Tags: activemq-classic, talend, esb

Can you please help me with the below scenario?

Q1. I am consuming messages from ActiveMQ and inserting the consumed messages in the Database table. For some reason, if Database is down I am losing the message. How can I prevent the message without losing them?

Q2. I have to consume the message from the Queue only when the target database is up and running.

I have created a Java Bean code to check the database is up and running. But I am stuck and not able to achieve that. Any help will be much appreciated, please.

Consume the message from the Queue only when the database is up and running.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Q1 : you can try to use the cErrorHandler component : it will allow you to catch errors happening on a flow, to redirect them to another route (using direct:myRoute as a deadLetter, you then have to configure your route beginning with a cDirect named myRoute. For example you can redirect the message to a folder, or another activeMQ Queue).

Q2 : I don't know how you could use this java bean, if you place it before the cJMS, Talend will consider the cJMS as a Producer component, not a consumer.

Comment: Hi Corentin,
I tried using the cErrorHandler component for the different scenario but the error is not captured. I need to capture the error message when JMS listener error and send an email notification. 

[ERROR]: org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TestQueue123' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:616161. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:616161

Comment: seems like your port is not correct. Default is 61616 . Are you sure about 616161 ?

Comment: Yes, I purposely did that for testing. For some reason, if the ActiveMQ service is down or Queue is not found I have to capture the error message and trigger an email notification. For some reason, I am not able to capture the information using cOnException or cErrorHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cTalend job before cJMS and create the database connection inside the cTalendJob and pass the return code outside the talend job and check in the route if it is 200 then redirect to the cJMS flow otherwise nothing.